# How to submit a guest post with rich text editor?

Tags: theme-development

I am looking for a way to design a form like this to allow my website visitors to submit guest posts.

[[image: image posted]]

These guest posts will then appear for preview and approval on admin area. From where, they can be accepted or rejected.

Here is the link to what I want to develop.

Can anybody give me a head start on this, in terms of backend development and especially getting the rich text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I did complete a project that have front end form to submit. But i used ACF Plugin for this purpose that allow us to create front end form and save them as draft. After review that post you can click on Publish button to show them on front end.

Please see the attached screenshot what i did in my case.

[image]

Let me know if it helps you.